# Seperate strings from array that have whitespace from those that dont have whitespaces in python

Tags: python, arrays, whitespace

I have an array that has strings in it and I want to make 2 new arrays, first array is the one that will have items from first list that have whitespaces and second array that has those who don't:

```
array = ["something", "something with space", "something2", "something with space 2"]
```

First:

```
noWhitespaceCharacters = ["something", "something2"]
```

Second:

```
hasWhitespaceCharacters = ["something with space", "something with space 2"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just check if there is whitespace or not by in keyword

```
array = ["something", "something with space", "something2", "something with space 2"]
nows=[i for i in array if " " in i]
ws = [i for i in array if " " not in i]
```

nows means no white space, ws means white space

Comment: This solution is incredibly inefficient. Consider if `array` contained 1 million items (try `array *= 250000`), the 2nd list comprehension is a huge point of contention. Much better would be: `ws = [i for i in array if " " not in i]` -- instead of checking `nows` each time, you simply check the string `i` itself, as in the first list comprehension.

Comment: absolutely correct. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split every words. The basic operator for `.split()` method is the whitespace, indeed. If the string is sub-divided into more pieces, it means it contains whitespaces.

```
no_white  = []
white = []

for val in array:
    if len(val.split()) > 1:
        white.append(val)
    else:
        no_white.append(val)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume *first array is the one that will have items from first list that have whitespaces and second array that has those who don't* has precedence over your example. You might use `set` arithmetic and built-in `string` module following way

```
import string
ws = set(string.whitespace)
arr = ["something", "something with space", "something2", "something\n\with\nnewline"]
without_ws = [i for i in arr if not ws.intersection(i)]
with_ws = [i for i in arr if ws.intersection(i)]
```

Explanation: `.interesction` provide common elements